# Create crosstab in SQL

Tags: sql

I hear that I need an array.  Not sure what that is and how it applies to my data.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

I have data returning in my query that looks like this

```
Pat#    | Action     | Date
--------+------------+----------
123456  | Sim        | 3/5/2014
123456  | DosiFusion | 3/6/2014
123456  | MDRX       | 3/7/2014
123456  | TxEnd      | 3/10/2014
123456  | Sim        | 3/22/2014
123456  | DosiFusion | 3/22/2014
123456  | MDApproval | 3/24/2014
123456  | TxEnd      | 3/28/2014
3210032 | Sim        | 3/5/2014
3210032 | RTT Review | 3/6/2014
3210032 | TxEnd      | 3/10/2014
```

I want to have this data go into a crosstab that looks like this
Columns are not matching with data but it should be clear what I want to do.

```
PatientId Sim       DosiFusion MDApproval MDRX      RTTReview TxEnd
--------- --------  ---------- ---------- --------  --------- ---------
123456    3/5/2014  3/6/2014   ---------  3/7/2014  --------- 3/10/2014
123456    3/22/2014 3/22/2014  3/24/2014  --------- --------- 3/28/2014
3210032   3/5/2014  ---------  ---------  --------- 3/6/2014  3/10/2014
```

Comment: Please add a tag for the exact version of SQL. Also be aware that about 1% of the internet is devoted to pages describing how to do a cross tab in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a table rotation, something like this:

```
select sim.patient_id as "Pat#"       ,
       sim.Date       as "Sim"        ,
       dos.Date       as "DosFusion"  ,
       mda.Date       as "MDApproval" ,
       mdx.Date       as "MDRX"       ,
       rtt.Date       as "RTTREview"  ,
       txe.Date       as "TxEnd"
from ( select *
       from my_table
       where Action = 'Sim'
     ) sim
left join my_table dos on dos.action      = 'DosiFusion'
                      and dos.patient_id  = sim.patient_id
                      and dos.Date       >= sim.Date
left join my_table mda on mda.action      = 'MDApproval'
                      and mda.patient_id  = p.patient_id
                      and mda.Date       >= coalesce(dos.Date,sim.Date)
left join my_table mdx on mdx.action      = 'MDRX'
                      and mdx.patient_id  = p.patient_id
                      and mdx.Date       >= coalesce(mda.Date,dos.Date,sim.Date)
left join my_table rtt on rtt.action      = 'RTT Review'
                      and rtt.patient_id  = p.patient_id
                      and rtt.Date       >= coalesce(mdx.Date,mda.Date,dos.Date,sim.Date)
left join my_table txe on txe.action      = 'TxEnd'
                      and txe.patient_id  = p.patient_id
                      and txe.Date       >= coalesce(rtt.Date,mdx.Date,mda.Date,dos.Date,sim.Date)
order by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get data in shape of crosstab
In sql 
You must use pivot table query
Check this link
[sql server pivot table](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx)